# Passport js, can't sign in after cookie has expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using passport js as authentication middleware, local strategy. It works. But when the cookie has expired, I can no longer login.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    mongoose.model('users').findOne({
      email: username,
      password: password
    }, function(err, result){
      if(result){
        var user = {
          name: result.name,
          email:result.email
        };
        return done(null, user);
      }else{
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
    });
  }
));
```

This is the LocalStrategy login. It returns the user correctly. But in my browser I can see that no cookie has been set.

If I restart my node, then it works again. What can be wrong here?

Comment: So, you can login once and then authenticated requests work, but you can't login again unless you restart node?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up session capabilities in express. In your app configuration there should be something like this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser()) // must come before session.
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'super hard to guess' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

If you're using express 4, you'll need two new dependencies, the `express-session` and `cookie-parser` modules, so instead it would be:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Yes I have done this. But the issue was that I hade maxAge: new date() + 360000 in my cookie setting. If I removed the new Date, it worked.