# Passport js is not working after cookie lifetime expired

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, passport.js, express-session

Recently I've found tricki bug in my express js project and I would be grateful for help with debugging it.

This is related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591982/passport-js-cant-sign-in-after-cookie-has-expired?answertab=active#tab-top), but answer is not resolving problem, because I want to specify `maxAge` and deleting this parameter from session configuration is not solution for me.

I am using Passport js + express-session

This is my session configuration:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'MySecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie  : {
        secure: false, // If it's true, login is not working as well
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * 30))    
    }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

To check that user is authenticated I'm using simple middleware:

```
middlewareObj.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/signin');
    }
};
```

Passport local-signin:

```
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, email, password, done) {
            var User = user;

            var isValidPassword = function (userpass, password) {
                return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass);
            }

            User.findOne({
                where: {
                    email: email
                }        
            }).then(function (user) {
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'User does not exists'));
            }

            if (!isValidPassword(user.dataValues.userPassword, password)) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Incorrect password.'));
            }

            return done(null, {user});

        }).catch(function (error) {
           return done(null, false, req.flash('error',error.message));
        });
    }
));
```

This is my logout route:

```
router.get('/logout',(req,res) => {
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Standard user login is working fine, after submitting sign in form user is `serialized` than `deserialized` and `isAuthenticated()` method returns `true`.

But cookie configuration(`maxAge` exactly) is making some problems. When cookie lifetime expired, next user's login is not working anymore. `isAuthenticated()` method is returning `false` (user object does't exist inside `req`).

After restarting server, user can login normally, but when cookie `maxAge` is reached, next login is not working again. Passport is not showing any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely has something to do with your `maxAge` value. The [expressjs/sessions package docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session) point out that `maxAge` is "the number (in milliseconds) to use when calculating the Expires Set-Cookie attribute".

You're passing a `Date` to `maxAge`; it's expecting the number of milliseconds until the cookie expires.